# Pinyin "jiu" / "you" final pronunciation difference

Tags: mandarin, difference, pinyin

In Mandarin should there be any difference between the pronunciation of the pinyin final in "jiu" and the pronunciation of the pinyin whole word "you"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pinyin Final "iu" contains a hidden "o", so it is pronounced "iou".

"y" is actually an "i" Final being used as an Initial.

So the answer is: if both are the same tones, no :)

Same tones as in: 就 (jiù) and 又 (yòu)